# Good Introductory Book on Logic for a Non-Mathematician

Tags: logic, soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation

Could anyone please advise a good introductory book on logic for a non-mathematician?

The one mentioned in this thread, which I found while looking for methods to solve logic games: [How to solve a "logic grid/table puzzle" as well as a "logic game" from the LSAT](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184127/how-to-solve-a-logic-grid-table-puzzle-as-well-as-a-logic-game-from-the-lsat) 
seemed good, but when I looked it up a bit more thoroughly on Amazon I found some terrible reviews, even some saying it's not 'logical' ...

Any advice?

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you want a book that will help you with puzzles and not a book on mathematical logic. Is that accurate?

Comment: This isn't necessarily a "book on logic", but if you are interested in logic, you should try reading "Gödel, Escher, Bach" by Douglas Hofstadter.

Comment: Can you tell us what purpose you have for learning logic? If it is to improve your everyday life reasoning skills, I have some ideas, and it will indeed be much more informal.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of books written for the standard beginning logic course in (U.S.) philosophy departments, and nearly all of these assume virtually no mathematical background, such as [Elementary Logic](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0070518971) by Michael D. Resnik, [Beginning Logic](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0915144506) by Edward J. Lemmon, [Introduction to Logic](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486406873) by Patrick Suppes, [Symbolic Logic](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0023249803) by Irving M. Copi, etc. Of course, avoid anything with "mathematical logic" in the title.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments!

Comment: @T. Gunn: in a way, yes, but I'm prepared to do some work to learn formal logic theory, too. The post I quoted seemed to imply that the methods described in Hurley's book can be applied to games.

Comment: @Bram28: see above. Mostly to learn some theory and methods that can be applied to logic games.

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro: they all look interesting; I just wonder what is most appropriate for what I want to achieve, meaning whether there are significant differences in what one learns from each of these books. As you can see, someone below cited Suppes, too. Maybe I'll give that one a try first...

Comment: Just to give context: I read [this book](https://www.amazon.com/McGraw-Hills-Conquering-Logic-Games-Third/dp/0071717889/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1498902822&sr=8-1&keywords=conquering+LSAT+logic+games) and found it quite interesting and useful, despite the negative reviews. But it does not explain formal logic, it just teaches you some techniques to solve problems. I'd like to understand if there is any foundation in formal logic behind such techniques.

Comment: @user6376297 OK, thanks, that gives me some idea what you're looking for. I have to run but will have some suggestions later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Introduction to logic by Patrick Suppes](http://web.mit.edu/gleitz/www/Introduction%20to%20Logic%20-%20P.%20Suppes%20(1957)%20WW.pdf)

[Cover](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41oVAjYdG0L._SX321_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg)

An excellent read aimed at philosophers. It goes into enough technical detail that it will benefit the mathematician as well.

Comment: Thank you! I'll start with this one and see if I can get my head around it. I tried to vote you up but apparently I don't have sufficient reputation.

Comment: @user6376297 you can accept the answer as opposed to an up-vote. I think accepting them also increases your reputation as well, so you may be able to up-vote things in the future.